# wavファイルのスペクトログラム表示で0除算例外

Tags: python

scipyとmatplotlibを使って音声ファイルのスペクトログラムを表示したいです。しかし下記の関数では0除算エラーが出てしまいました。

```
def show_spec(fn):
    sample_rate, X = wavfile.read(fn)
    print sample_rate, X[:,0].shape
    specgram(X[:,0], Fs=sample_rate)
```

実行結果

```
44100 (442991,)
python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:7042: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)
```

なぜでしょうか。

Comment: `log10(0)`のような計算を行ったから。

Comment: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/specgram-Warning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log10-td8468.html
上記のreplyが参考になるかもね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.specgram`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram) はデフォルトでは信号の強さを対数スケールに変換して描画します。もしある周波数の強さが `0` だとすると `log10(0)` となり、計算結果が `-∞` 、加えて[0除算例外](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man7/math_error.7.html#lbAF)が発生することになります。

プログラムが間違っているわけではありません。

無音部分が原因ならそれを取り除くか完全な無音ではなくするという方法もあると思いますが、 `with np.errstate(divide='ignore')` の中で `specgram` を呼び出せば抑制できるかもしれません。
<sub>試してないですし、その対応が適切かどうか私にはわかりませんが・・・。</sub>

参考： [RuntimeWarning: Divide by Zero error: How to avoid? PYTHON, NUMPY - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25088239/2818869)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
パラメータを変更したところ例外は発生しなくなりました。